# How can I use a "variable" in an if/or statement in PHP to generate a statement conditionally?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, parse-error

I have zero experience with PHP. I run a wordpress site, and am trying to make one simple modification to the code. This is what I have:

```
    <?php
    if(<?php the_author() ?> == "Joe Man")
    {
    <?php the_author() ?>
    }
    ?>
```

I believe all variables start with a $, so what I have above in my if statement is not a variable. What do I do? I also tried creating a variable, as below:

```
    <?php
    $author = <?php the_author() ?>
    if($author == "Joe Man")
    {
    <?php the_author() ?>
    }
    ?>
```

Neither of the above worked. So my question is how can I get that if statement to evaluate? What I need is if the_author is "Joe Man", for the string "Joe Man" to display on my page.

This is the error I get btw:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Thanks!

Comment: PHP in PHP ... the new inception!

Comment: lol had no idea I had gone that far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not nest `<?php ?>` tags. The correct code would be:

```
<?php
    $author = get_the_author();
    if ($author == "Joe Man") {
        echo $author;
    }
?>
```

Actually, the variable could be skipped altogether, shortening the code to:

```
<?php
    if (get_the_author() == "Joe Man") {
        the_author();
    }
?>
```

Note the echo to print out the author.

Comment: Surely you meant to echo $author in the top example instead of the_author(). It sort of makes the variable assignment pointless if you don't.

Comment: Hence I stated the variable could be skipped altogether. Though you are right. I'll fix.

Comment: I understand now. But something strange is happening. Simply having this bit of code: the_author(); no matter where, displays the name on my page. For the shortened version, if the_author is Joe Man, Joe Man appears three times: once for the echo command and twice for the two instances of the_author in the code.

Comment: Then it means the the function `the_author()` does not return the author name, it prints it. In which case, you'd want to call `get_the_author()` which will return it.

Comment: Love you guys. There should be a programmer appreciation day, seriously. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using wordpress, so beyond your PHP-in-PHP error, your code wouldn't work anyways, as both `the_author()` calls will simply OUTPUT the data, instead of returning it for comparison. You'd want:

```
$author = get_the_author();
if ($author == "Joe Man") {
   echo $author;
}
```

instead. As a general rule, any function in Wordpress which does output has a `get_...()` variant which returns instead of outputting.

Answer (score 1):

If the author is "Joe Man", output the author:

```
<?php
  $author = the_author();
  if($author == "Joe Man") {
    echo $author;
  }
?>
```

Comment: What you said works, but for some reason, running this bit of code: the_author(); no matter where, makes the name display on the page. Is there a way to suppress this?